# I'm trying to make sense of an error

Tags: python-2.7, function

Okay, I'm not quite sure what the error is that I need to focus on, I'm assuming it's the first error to do with parameters that has then caused the following errors. But I wanted to know what this error is signifying. From what I know try and except is used for file handling/manipulation. So does that mean the error is linked to the fact that `/opt/MOST-master/MLST_data/TEST/reference.seq` doesn't exist? Because I checked and it doesn't exist, but I presume that's because it file that is expected to be there, but isn't because of the initial error of the try and except.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/MOST-master/modules/utility_functions.py", line 243, in try_and_except
return function(*parameters, **named_parameters)
File "/opt/MOST-master/modules/MLST_extract_flanking_region_functions.py", line 74, in flanking_regions
refseq_record = SeqIO.read(reference_fasta_file, "fasta", generic_dna)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 676, in read
first = next(iterator)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/SeqIO/__init__.py", line 592, in parse
with as_handle(handle, mode) as fp:
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/Bio/File.py", line 87, in as_handle
with open(handleish, mode, **kwargs) as fp:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/MOST-master/MLST_data/TEST/reference.seq'
```

Comment: The error is an uncaught "No such file" exception. You have probably have a bad BioPython installation, but without the code that caused this error, it is impossible to tell.

Answer (score 0):

In the error output, you see the direct cause of the error at the bottom. The call stack is presented with the outermost frame at the top.

For example this program

```
def a(x):
    b(x)

def b(x):
    c(x)

def c(x):
    d(x)

a(3)
```

yields this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stk.py", line 10, in <module>
    a(3)
  File "stk.py", line 2, in a
    b(x)
  File "stk.py", line 5, in b
    c(x)
  File "stk.py", line 8, in c
    d(x)
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
```

Comment: So the last line `No such file or directory: '/opt/MOST-master/MLST_data/TEST/reference.seq'` is the problem?